# Replace SingletonPattern by using IOC Container based architecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a legacy winForms application that now I'm in charge of maintaining and developing.
This app has a lot of singleton instance....
Some are very similar to service that wrap other component or class other instead wrap some entities to making a cache-like pattern

This is an example of this cached class

```
public class SingletonCycle
{
    private static Cycle _instance;
    private static DevExpress.RackManager.RackManager _rackManager;

    public static event EventHandler<Cycle> OnCycleUpdated;

    private static void RaiseOnCycleUpdated(Cycle cycle)
    {
        OnCycleUpdated?.Invoke(cycle, cycle);
    }

    public static Cycle GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }
    
    public static void SetCycleInstance(Cycle cycle)
    {
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            SingletonAuditTrail.GetInstance().ModifiedCycle(cycle);
        }
        else
        {
            SingletonAuditTrail.GetInstance().StartCycle(cycle);
        }
        _instance = cycle;
        _instance.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        _instance.Operator = CommonUIManager.GetInstance().GetConfig().GetCurrentUser;

        SaveCycle();
    }
}
```

Because I want to test some part of the software I want to transform all this singleton in service that will be registered in container as singleton Lifestyle.
The problem is that all this services are spread out in all the software and for now I can't use everywhere constructor injection because i can't put all the classes inside container.
For now I try to use the container as static and everywhere use it instead of every singleton instances

**Are there any problems of using container instead static singleton? Can you suggest some other advice to replace effectively singleton?**

Only as an example to explain....This is my first try example of this implementation with DI and simpleInjector

Register container in the static Main

```
public static Container Container { get; private set; }

static void Main()
{
........
    var crpConfig = SingletonCrpCompactConfig.GetInstance();
    var container = new Container();
    
    container.Register(typeof(UnitOfWorkManager),
        CreateUOWManager(crpConfig),
        Lifestyle.Singleton);
    container.Register(typeof(RecipeModuleCache),
        CreateRecipeModuleCache(crpConfig, container),
        Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Verify();
    Container = container;
......
}

private static Func<object> CreateUOWManager(CrpCompactConfig crpConfig)
{
    return () => new UnitOfWorkManager(crpConfig.ConnectionString);
}

private static Func<object> CreateRecipeModuleCache(CrpCompactConfig crpConfig, Container container)
{
    return () =>
    {
        var uowManager = container.GetInstance<UnitOfWorkManager>();
        var cache = new RecipeModuleCache(crpConfig, uowManager);
        return cache;
    };
}
```

Example of the service to be registered inside the container

```
public class RecipeModuleCache
{
    private readonly CrpCompactConfig _config;
    private readonly UnitOfWorkManager _uow;
    private CrpCompactRecipeModule _instance;
    private bool _cached;

    public RecipeModuleCache(CrpCompactConfig config, UnitOfWorkManager uow)
    {
        _config = config;
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public CrpCompactRecipeModule GetCached()
    {
        if (_cached)
            return _instance;
        _instance = StaticBuilders.Create(_uow);
        _cached = true;
        return _instance;
    }

    public void Invalidate()
    {
        _instance = null;
        _cached = false;
    }
}
```

So when there is the singleton i use instead

```
Program.Container.GetInstance<RecipeModuleCache>()
```